# Developing paid extensions for Visual Studio Marketplace

Tags: visual-studio

I want to develop a commercial extension for Visual Studio 2017. The [Visual Studio Marketplace](http://marketplace.visualstudio.com) has free, trial and paid extensions.

I can find info only for VSTS extensions, where Microsoft does for you billing, support, etc. For a regular (non-VSTS) extension, will the marketplace do billing for me? I can't find any info on this.

Comment: I'm inclined to say this is not a programming question, but a commercial question.

Comment: @MSalters Microsoft's support site says to ask these questions on StackOverflow. Besides, AWS, Google, etc. all have SO tags for questions related to their marketplaces.

Comment: There are certainly programmatic aspects to VSTS extensions and other marketplaces, and on those topics you can ask questions. This particularly involves packaging your app such that it meets technical requirements.. But "will they do billing?" isn't one of those questions.

Comment: @ColeWu-MSFT You may want to create a "visual-studio-marketplace" tag or something like that. I don't have enough rep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a regular VS extension you need to implement billing yourself.